# When does the string.compare stops comparing? (std)

Tags: c++, string

I know that the compare method will return an integer value denoting something like the difference between the two strings (or 0 if matched).  My question  is, in the case the a mismatch is found, does it stop comparing at the mismatch or it finishes until it was specified?

Does it depends on the compiler or is it standard? I am currently using gcc 4.1.2

Comment: Why would anyone possibly continue comparing after the result of the comparison has already been established?

Comment: Why do you care? If it’s out of performance concerns, rest assured that the library will do the right thing. But they right thing *may* involve looking at characters after the first unequal one (for instance on architectures where it’s more efficient to compare several bytes at a time).

Comment: Maybe some kind of security measure? I remember reading about attacks on PIN numbers based on the fact that ATMs stopped checking PIN after first digit mismatch, giving the worst case scenario of 40 tries to get 4 digit PIN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the standard doesn't care, but the result of the compare -- the standard only cares about that -- is entirely dependent on the first non-matching character. So comparing the others would be rather pointless for any implemention, except possibly a few more characters if it's easier to handle wrt to caches or word sizes of the platform.

Answer (score 1):

It is not specified.

The standard states that `rhs.compare(lhs)` is equivalent to `char_traits::compare(&rhs[0], &lhs[0], min(rhs.size(), lhs.size())`. `char_traits::compare` is described to discard the values of character comparisons past a mismatch, but whether or not it actually reads the characters is not detailed any further.